# Run Databricks notebook jobs via API in a shared context

Tags: rest, apache-spark, databricks

In the REST documentation for Databricks, you can submit a notebook task as a job to a cluster using the 2.0 API or you can submit a command or python script using the 1.2 API

The 1.2 API allows you to create a context and then all subsequent commands or scripts can be submitted against this context. This allows you to maintain state (dataframes, variables etc) which is much more akin to running notebooks interactively in the browser

What i want is to be able to submit my notebooks into the same context and get the same behaviour as the 1.2 API but this does not seem possible, is there a reason for that? Or am i missing something if it can be done?

My use case is i want to be able to re-run a notebook from the API and have it remember its last state (in the most basic example just knowing its already loaded a dataframe) but more generally having the ability for subsequent jobs to only run what changed since the last run.

As far as I can tell, failing the ability to do this via the 2.0 API, I have 2 options:

- Convert my notebook to Python script and have a bootstrap script on client side that invokes an entry point using the 1.2 API within the same context
- Create temp tables at checkpoints in my notebook and possibly maintain a special variables dataframe of state variables

Both of these seem unecessarily complex, any other ideas?